# Steam is not working

Tags: steam

I installed Steam through terminal and it installs fine. Every time I try to launch the application, it acts like it's going to start but doesn't. I tried to launch it through terminal with `steam` and this comes up.

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2015-09-22 00:55:03] Startup - updater built Aug 19 2015 11:27:40
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Well I just restarted my system and it seemed to have worked. So just ignore this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I think this is the `opengl` library missing. Did you install the dependencies of steam when you installed the `.deb` file ?

You can easily do that by typing this command after the installation:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

If this didn't work, try to do a fresh install and remember always to install dependencies when installing a `.deb` file, because `dpkg` doesn't do that for you !